# Bamboo is giving perforce error for a build

Tags: perforce, bamboo

```
22-Aug-2014 11:03:15    version:
22-Aug-2014 11:03:15         [echo] 1.0.0-MAIN-22328-23.${build.number}
22-Aug-2014 11:03:15    
22-Aug-2014 11:03:15    revert:
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17       [p4edit] error: Invalid changelist number '${p4.change}'.
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17    
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17    BUILD FAILED
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17    c:\Build\XXX\build.xml:189: error: Invalid changelist number     '${p4.change}'.
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17    
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17    
22-Aug-2014 11:03:17    Total time: 2 seconds
```

Following is the error I am getting on my Bamboo build, initially 3 builds ago everything was working fine until this error started getting thrown 
Nothing was changed in perforce or in Bamboo

Any tips as to what is going wrong???

Thanks in advance

--UK

Comment: It would probably be easier to debug if you posted the ant code.

Comment: It appears as though your Bamboo variables are no longer being set.  The console output you've posted shows the literal values '${p4.change}' and '${build.number}' are being passed into your build script and causing P4 to choke when trying to checkout changelist numbered "${p4.change}" as that string is not a number.  Check the Bamboo Audit Log for unexpected build plan adjustments, the P4 repository configuration in Bamboo, then check in the rest of the log to see if your variables are being exposed instead as ${bamboo.VARIABLENAMEHERE}.

Comment: Yes, I checked the Bamboo variables, since the upgrade something changed and I could not set the variables. It was a permission issue